# A prob =a random variable

Tags: probability

When I read some proofs, some authors conclude that $P(A)=I_{A}$, where $A$ is an event and $I$ is the indicator function. They mean that $P(A)$ can take either $0$ or $1$. However, I do not understand this point very well.The problem I am not satisfactory is that when $P(A)=1$, it means $A$ must happen while $P(A)=0$, $A$ cannot happen. However, RHS is a r.v. which means that if $\omega$ is found in $A$, it takes $1$ while if $\omega$ is not in $A$, it takes $0$. Two things are not related! Could someone elaborate their ideas a little bit here?

Comment: Are you sure that they do not say $\Pr(A)=E[I_A] $ so the probability is the expectation of the indicator function?

Comment: Correct answer.  Post as an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: Almost sure that $P(A)=E(I_A)$ is *not* the question. To prove is the more interesting implication that if $P(A)=I_A$ almost surely then $P(A)=0$ or $P(A)=1$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist More caution, please.

Comment: As an example, take a look at a description of Kolmorogov's 0-1 law...it's a theorem that concludes basically the same thing for a particular class of events called "tail events" (e.g., the event that you never toss a head, probably that at some point, you will always throw an even number on a die, etc.) Often it is not easy to determine which value it is, so you can express this as you have in your post: $P(A)=I_A$

Comment: I read this when I read the proof of Kolmorgov 0-1 law. I understand it is difficult to determine which value it is, but simply writing P(A)=I_A is meaningless. P(A) is a value which takes either 0 or 1, but I_A is a random variable. Two things are totally different. Do you mean that it is just a math representation only?

Answer (score 2):

*Comment converted to answer as requested:*

I suspect they said something like $$\Pr(A)=E[I_A]$$ so the probability of the event is the expectation of the indicator function. The indicator function can be seen as a random variable taking the values $0$ or $1$ so its expectation being a real number in the range from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: I suspect this is offtopic, see comment.